# Real-time output not working for TFS build

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Recently I have upgraded our TFS 2015 update 1 to update 2. All the builds are working fine but the real-time output for the build is not showing? Any thoughts on that? But when we view the build in the TFS hosted server the Console shows the live update

Update: 
Output screen from remote machine[image]
Output screen from the server where Tfs is running [image]

Comment: Are you using XAML build or vNext build? What's real-time output? Could you share a screenshot?

Comment: Hi @cece-msft I am using vNext build. Real-time output is the build-log that shows the new file get and/or project on current build and/or test currently running. I refer to the screenshot above where you can see that the build is running but the Console is saying "Waiting for console output from an agent..."

Comment: I'm also using TFS 2015 Update2, but don't have this issue. Please try to reconfigure your build agent, to see whether the issue persists.

Comment: Do you have firewall enabled on the machine? And a similar issue for your reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1a6499ee-150b-400a-9fed-1f681e762ce4/tfs-2015-build-vnext-hangs-with-waiting-for-console-output-from-an-agent?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: I'm also missing the live or real-time output, but in the Release part. Also performing Powershell on Target Machine. The log will be available, but only after the step is completed. I know it should be able to display the log "as it goes", just like when running the script locally.

I know this topic is old, but there is still no answer and I can't find the answer elsewhere either.

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem with TFS 2017 when we disabled Basic Authentication for the TFS website (which is acutally kinda mandatory for later TFS versions for Personal Access Tokens to work). After re-enabeling Basic Authentication we also saw the live console again.

Comment: In my case (TFS 2019) an occasional time synchronization problem with the AD domain controller seems to be the root cause. Fix is to restart the TFS server after getting the DC working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to have log as the screenshot below shows:

[image]

If you are using the vNext build, you can download the log and check file **1_Build.txt**:

[image]

If you are using XAML build, you can go to drop location and check file **ActivityLog.xml** under folder logs.

Comment: Hi @cece-msft, Thanks for sharing the info. I know that I can download the build log but when you see "The build has been queued and is waiting to start" but in fact build is running in the background and you have to wait till the build finish to get a log is a bit annoying. Moreover, it was working just before we upgrade to update 2

Comment: I'm also using TFS 2015 Update2, but don't have this issue. Please try to reconfigure your build agent, to see whether the issue persists.

Comment: My company has this problem, too.  I've seen it work once or twice, so I know it *can* work, but it does NOT work 99% of the time in Internet Explorer.  It works about 30% of the time for me if I watch with Chrome.  I queue a lot of builds, so I have a large sample size.